# Why did VBA code to build charts stop working between version 16.26 and 16.27?

Tags: excel, vba, version

I have a block of code I reuse throughout my macro that builds charts modified from [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/3/1/the-vba-coding-guide-for-excel-charts-graph). It's worked fine for about a year but now half of my users are having trouble. I figured out this morning that those that installed version 16.27 (for mac...most recent version) could no longer use the code while users using 16.26 had no trouble.

I can't find anything online that states a similar issue. I started getting and error that says "Compile error: Method or data member not found" as soon as the code runs. The VBA editor highlights this specific section of code: 
    cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

```
Public Sub LangSampArticChart()
'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are required)

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As ChartObject

'Data range for the chart 
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A30:F35")

'Designates which cell to place the top left corner of the graph in
ActiveSheet.Range("H25").Select

'Create chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
  Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
  Width:=360, _
  Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
  Height:=216)

'Give chart some data
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

'Determine the chart type
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

'Remove Major Gridlines
cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete

'Add Data Labels on Outside End
cht.Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd)

'Set Maximum Y-Axis Scale and Define Number Format
With cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MaximumScale = 1
    .Crosses = xlCustom
End With
cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"

'Sets Gap Width (Column Width)
cht.Chart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 100

'Sets the legend to the bottom of the graph
cht.Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)

'Colors All Bars Grayscale
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.35
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(4).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

cht.Select
End Sub
```

I expect the chart to build as defined by the code. However, I can't get passed the compiler. Are there any known issues with version 16.27? Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about just `cht.SetSourceData`?

Comment: I gave that a shot but still get the same result. It's like defining the variable as a ChartObject doesn't bring up the associated references for some reason.

Comment: Hm, interesting - I pasted your code to my VBE exactly, and did *not* get an error on the `cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng` line, or any line. It ran as expected.  One suggestion, change `ActiveSheet` to be the actual sheet reference you're running this on, e.g. `Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A30:F35")`...

Comment: I worked on it for six hours yesterday and wound up writing new code. However, while I was working on it the original code started working (I have buttons added in multiple places to create charts for different data sets, but the code is fundamentally the same). I pasted all the original code back in and everything started working again. It was REALLY odd. I'd say it was just my computer but I had about a dozen users having the same problem. It was only users that had the most recent update to Excel so maybe there was a bug in the update. Thank you so much for your help!!!